# Reporting vulnerability to New York Times

Tags: disclosure

I have successfully discovered a vulnerability in the New York Times website. Is there any known way I can report this? I have not attacked it. But I found a bypass. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not have a specific security contact listed, so you should email `help@nytimes.com` and ask for your message to be forwarded to their IT security department.

Comment: Thank you I sent the email to them. Im wating. Also trying to contact them via linkedin but it is difficult

Comment: @LuisCarlos You'll almost never get good results from trying individual back-channels if you haven't first tried official channels like their standard contact point.

Comment: Of course I have never done this. So I'm asking the ethical way.Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have found this in all the majority of the websites... Strange....

Comment: @LuisCarlos Are you sure it's a vulnerability then? What _kind_ of vuln is it?

Answer (score -1):

I see that my answer is too late, but I'm going to give it anyway because I believe it will be useful to others, although likely Controversial.

> **Do not report vulnerabilities by identifiable or traceable methods!**

In a reasonable and rational world, the recipient of your vulnerability report should thank you, unfortunately that is more often not the case. The more common response is to accuse you of hacking their system. People have been arrested for things as simple as changing a parameter in a URL. "*Shoot the messenger*" is alive and well.

If you can't report it anonymously, don't report it at all. Stay well clear and tell no one.

I assure you, I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: It all depends on who you are reporting to.

Comment: I reported to them and they promissed me they would not sue me for anything.

Comment: I sent them so unitl now nothing new.

Comment: "_I assure you, I know what I'm talking about._"; why does that leave me less-assured than i would be not having read it?